# React Native TypeError after upgrading version to 0.60.4

Tags: android, react-native, runtime-error, version, upgrade

I have a huge app in React Native and I am working to build it only on Android for now. I have to upgrade react-native version >= 0.59 to make it compatible with new google policy for 64 bit devices as I was not able  to update my app on play store anymore. However, I tried a lot to update react-native version in my existing app but I tried around 2 days but it was a headache and it didn't go well as expected.

Now what I am doing is, I created a new react-native app which was built on latest react-native version 0.60.4. I copied all my code from my existing app to new app including index.js. But before any changes, code was working fine but as soon as I shift my previous code to new app it stopped working. I resolved most of the error but now it is giving error as below:

```
TypeError: Object is not a function (near '...(0,S.default)...')
                             │
                             │ This error is located at:
                             │ in Te
                             │ in f
                             │ in RCTView
                             │ in RCTView
                             └ in c
```

My previous code is up to date and working fine. And from above error I couldn't determine where and what the actual issue is. Please help me here.

My index.js:

```
const Navigation = () => StackNavigator(
 {
   SplashScreen: {screen : SplashScreen},
   MapScreen:{screen:MapScreen},

   // Login screens
   SignUpScreen: {screen : SignUpScreen},
},
 {
   initialRouteName: 'SplashScreen',
   transitionConfig,
   headerMode: 'none',
   navigationOptions: {
     headerVisible: false
   }
 }
);

class MyApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('this.props in MyApp SplashScreen', this.props); // This will list the initialProps.

    return <Navigation screenProps={this.props} />; 
  }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => MyApp);
```

My initialRouteScreen is SplashScreen as below:

```
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, AsyncStorage,Picker,StyleSheet,TextInput,Dimensions,Linking, ToastAndroid,Text, View, Image,TouchableOpacity,TouchableWithoutFeedback} from 'react-native';
import Colors from '../utils/Res/Colors';
import Strings from '../utils/Res/Strings';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import {DeviceEventEmitter, NativeModules} from 'react-native';
import ApiService from '../network/ApiService';
import CustomDialog from '../customViews/dialog/CustomDialog';
var FCM = NativeModules.FCM;
type Props = {};
export default class SplashScreen extends Component<Props>
{
      constructor(args) {
        super(args);
        let { width } = Dimensions.get("window");
        apiService = new ApiService();
        this.state = {
           screenWidth: width,
           userPIN:'',
           showUpdateDialog:false,
           isUpdateAvailabe:false,
         }
      }

    componentWillMount(){
      FCM.getAppVersion((update) => {
        if(update){
          this.setState({showUpdateDialog:true});
          this.setState({isUpdateAvailabe:true});
        }
        // console.log("SplashScreen", "componentWillMount getAppVersion : " + update);
      });
    }

    componentDidUnmount(){
      DeviceEventEmitter.removeListener(Strings.fingerPrintEventName, this.listener)
    }
     componentDidMount(){
      console.log("SplashScreen", "componentDidMount Props: " + this.props.screenProps.DeepLink_TransactionID);
      this.listener = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(Strings.fingerPrintEventName, response => {
        console.log("Event Listener called : " + response);
        if(response === 1){
          this.props.navigation.replace("HomeScreen", {data: this.props.screenProps.notification})
        } else {
          ToastAndroid.show("Fingerprint detection falied", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        }
      });

      //  if (this.props.screenProps.notification){
      //   console.log("SplashScreen", "componentDidMount Props notification: " + this.props.screenProps.notification);
      //  } else {
      //   console.log("SplashScreen", "componentDidMount Props no notification");
      //  }
          this.refs.viewLogo.fadeOutLeft(5);
          setTimeout(()=>{
               this.refs.viewLogo.zoomIn(700);
          }, 100);

           this.timeoutHandle = setTimeout(()=>{
                this.getUserData();
           }, 2500);
     }

     componentWillUnmount(){
          clearTimeout(this.timeoutHandle);
     }

     getUserData(){
       if(this.state.isUpdateAvailabe){
         return;
       }
      AsyncStorage.multiGet([Strings.prefLoginID, Strings.prefFingerPrintEnable, Strings.prefUserPIN]).then(response => {
         if (response[0][1] === null || response[0][1] === 'null' || response[0][1] === undefined || response[0][1] === '') {
           AsyncStorage.setItem(Strings.prefIsFirstTime, "" + true);
           this.props.navigation.replace("SignUpScreen", {data: this.props.screenProps.notification})
         } else {
          AsyncStorage.setItem(Strings.prefIsFirstTime, "" + false);
           if(response[1][1] === "true"){
              var user_pin = response[2][1];
              FCM.isDeviceCompatible((response) => {
                if(response === true){
                  FCM.isFingerPrintAvailable((response) => {
                    console.log("isFingerPrintAvailable response : " + response);
                    if(response === true){
                      FCM.buildBioMetric(true);
                    } else {
                      ToastAndroid.show("Add Fingerprint to your device Settings", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
                    }
                  });
                } else {
                    if (user_pin != null && user_pin != undefined && user_pin != ""){
                      this.props.navigation.replace("AuthenticatePINScreen", {data: this.props.screenProps.notification})
                    } else {
                      this.props.navigation.replace("HomeScreen", {data: this.props.screenProps.notification})
                    }
                }
              });
            } else {
              this.props.navigation.replace("HomeScreen", {data: this.props.screenProps.notification})
            }
         }
       })
     }
     onDialogOkClick(){
      console.log("onDialogOkClick");
      this.setState({showUpdateDialog:false});
      Linking.openURL("market://details?id=com.m_naira");
     }

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.root}>
            <View style = {{flex:1}}>
                <View style = {{width:this.state.screenWidth,flex:1,position:'absolute',marginTop:130,marginBottom:30,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
                  <Text style={styles.TitleMessageTextStyle}>m-naira</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.MessageTextStyle}>{Strings.splashMessage}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style = {{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
                  <Animatable.Image ref="viewLogo" style={styles.LogoImageStyle} source={require('../images/ic_launcher.png')}/>
                </View>
            </View>
            {<CustomDialog message = {Strings.msgAppUpdate} showCancel = {false} okText = {"UPDATE"} onOkPress = {() => {this.onDialogOkClick()}}  visibility = {this.state.showUpdateDialog}/>}
          </View>
        );
      }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  root: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: Colors.appBGColor
  },
  LogoImageStyle: {width:150, height:150},

  MessageTextStyle: {width:280,textAlign:"center",color:Colors.appColor,fontSize:14},

  TitleMessageTextStyle: {width:200,textAlign:"center",color:Colors.appColor,fontSize:20,fontWeight:"bold"}
});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mNairaUpgrade",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "android": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-image-mapper": "0.0.14",
    "react-moment": "^0.9.2",
    "react-native": "0.60.4",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-contacts": "^5.0.2",
    "react-native-datepicker-dialog": "0.0.9",
    "react-native-geocoder": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.3.9",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.25.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.25.0",
    "react-native-qrcode": "^0.2.7",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^5.1.2",
    "react-native-scan-barcode": "^3.1.5",
    "react-native-signature-capture": "^0.4.9",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.6.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
    "url-search-params": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.5.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.5.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "24.8.0",
    "eslint": "6.1.0",
    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Provide screenshot please.